# Как подключиться к SQl server

Tags: sql, sql-server, flutter

Как подключиться к SQL Server в Flutter для использования в Android?
Вот-так выглядела строка подключения к базе данных в c#

```cs
Data Source=BCAD09H\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyBase;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets = True; Application Name = EntityFramework
```